# How to get started with scssphp

Tags: php, sass

Can't get started with https://github.com/leafo/scssphp.

Trying out with:

```
<?php
//(I live in directory /tests)
require('../scss.inc.php');
$dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\scssphp-master\tests\inputs';  //tried 'inputs'
scss_server::serveFrom($dir);
//outputs:
/* INPUT NOT FOUND scss v0.1.5 */
?>
```

Sorry for crying but docs at http://leafo.net/scssphp is out of reach, flagged by firewall as "chat"

Answer (score 0):

Try a relative path to your directory and that directory should be located in your project relative from your PHP file where you have added your code.

```
<?php
$directory = "stylesheets";
// Or this: $directory = __DIR__."/stylesheets";

require "scssphp/scss.inc.php";
scss_server::serveFrom($directory);
```

Comment: Tried moving test-scipt to package root as well as the /inputs-dir. Doesn't work. However, sccss->compile works. Unless I'm doing something utterly stupid, I'm filing a bug at scssphp github.